# Angular - cannot find module

Tags: angular, jhipster

I created app using JHipster (simple Java + Angular app). When I compile project to prod profile, I get
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgNEJ.png).
Admin Module is added using AppRoutingModule, code below:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        {
          path: 'admin',
          loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#DepozytKlAdminModule'
        },
        ...LAYOUT_ROUTES
      ],
      { enableTracing: false }
    )
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DepozytKlAppRoutingModule {}
```

And also app.module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgxWebstorageModule.forRoot({ prefix: 'dkl', separator: '-' }),
    NgJhipsterModule.forRoot({
      // set below to true to make alerts look like toast
      alertAsToast: false,
      alertTimeout: 5000,
      i18nEnabled: true,
      defaultI18nLang: 'pl'
    }),
    DepozytKlSharedModule.forRoot(),
    DepozytKlCoreModule,
    DepozytKlHomeModule,
    DepozytKlAccountModule,
    DepozytKlEntityModule,
    DepozytKlAppRoutingModule,
    // jhipster-needle-angular-add-module JHipster will add new module here
  ],
  declarations: [ ... ],
  providers: [ ... ],
  bootstrap: [DklMainComponent]
})
export class DepozytKlAppModule {
  constructor(private dpConfig: NgbDatepickerConfig) {
    this.dpConfig.minDate = { year: moment().year() - 100, month: 1, day: 1 };
  }
}
```

Interesting fact is that PROD profile works (entities section), I have problems with admin module. 
admin.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    DepozytKlSharedModule,
    /* jhipster-needle-add-admin-module - JHipster will add admin modules here */
    RouterModule.forChild(adminState),
    DepozytKlOrganisationModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AuditsComponent,
    UserMgmtComponent,
    UserMgmtDetailComponent,
    UserMgmtUpdateComponent,
    UserMgmtDeleteDialogComponent,
    LogsComponent,
    DklConfigurationComponent,
    DklHealthCheckComponent,
    DklHealthModalComponent,
    DklDocsComponent,
    DklMetricsMonitoringComponent,
    UserMgmtUpdateExtendedComponent
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: JhiLanguageService, useClass: JhiLanguageService }],
  entryComponents: [
    UserMgmtDeleteDialogComponent,
    DklHealthModalComponent,
    UserMgmtUpdateExtendedComponent,
    OrganisationTreeSelectionComponent,
    OrganisationTreeComponent
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class DepozytKlAdminModule {
  constructor(private languageService: JhiLanguageService, private languageHelper: JhiLanguageHelper) {
    this.languageHelper.language.subscribe((languageKey: string) => {
      if (languageKey !== undefined) {
        this.languageService.changeLanguage(languageKey);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: which version of Angular do you use? And show us your admin.module.ts (is your admin module is called admin.module.ts or depozyt.admin.module.ts?)

Comment: Can you include the source code of your ./admin/admin.module file?

Comment: Angular 7.2.12. admin.module.ts added above

Comment: just to make sure, does the path to admin.module correct? it's relative to your routing module - ./admin/admin.module. So next to routing module, you have a folder `admin` with module in it?

Comment: The path is correct. 
In folder app I have:
- app.module.ts,
- app.routing.ts,
- folder admin with admin.module.ts inside.

I've also checked the path in compressed war - it seems to be correct

Comment: It occures only in prod profile. Dev works properly

Answer (score 0):

Not properly connected OrganisationModule and Organisation Components. Solved